# php removing www from url

Tags: php, url, https

I am getting an error on a FB app when the url does not have the https or and has a www in the url. I am just going to strip the url of the www.

The code below adds the https if it is not in the url but **how would I remove the www as well**?

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirect");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
    $redirect = str_replace('www.', '', "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirect");
}
```

easiest way.

Comment: It was missing an ) at the end. I fixed it and it works.

Comment: Updated for posterity

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: er he was looking for ... `https` as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with your `.htaccess` with `https`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

- first line turns your `RewriteEngine` ... `On`
- second line checks to see if `https` is ... `on` or
- third line we check to see if the domain name starts with `www`
- fourth line if either of the above conditions match rewrite the domain