# Why LTRIM behaving like this in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string `www.waada.com`

Why

`ltrim("www.waada.com", "www.")` returns `aada.com`

OR

`ltrim("www.waada.com", "ww.")` returns `aada.com`

OR

`ltrim("www.waada.com", "w.")` returns `aada.com`

I want `waada.com` as final output.

It should just trim "www." from left side of the word.

Comment: Then why do you use ltrim()? Have you read the manual? Use str_replace($str, "www.","");

Comment: Because second argument is a __list of symbols__, not a __word__

Comment: @Andreas `str_replace(www.waadawww.com, "www.", "")` will have incorrect results

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005517/php-removing-www-from-url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336281/php-remove-www-from-url-inside-a-string

Comment: @Umair well that was not your question. If that is the case the Substr the string so you only replace at the start of the string

Comment: Why downvote? its not a stupid question

Comment: If you would have read the manual about the function you tried to use it would be obvious. `You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. **Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.**`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is as per comment with www at the end then use preg_replace.

```
Echo preg_replace("/^www\./", "", "www.waadawww.com");
```

https://3v4l.org/6cGV4

The pattern is:
At start of string match literally `www.` and replace with nothing

Comment: @Neodan and preg_replace is even better ;-)

Comment: yes `preg_replace` is perfect in this situation... I that and have in mind but somehow wrote `preg_match`  :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
<?php

echo preg_replace("/^www\./","","www.waadawww.com");
```

https://eval.in/856795

If you are allergic you can avoid regex altogether, but I find the above code much cleaner:

```
<?php

$url = "www.waadawww.com";
echo strpos($url, "www.") === 0 ? substr($url, 4) : $url;
```

https://eval.in/856813